# liferay: max_allowed_packet error

Tags: mysql, tomcat, liferay

I have already set everything in MySQL,

max_allowed_packet is set to 1024M and My application server and database server both are on Ubuntu.

After day or two I am getting error like Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

This error goes away as soon as I restart my server instance.

But I need some permanent solution with this. As we are serving with just one Liferay instance this restarts are impacting our business.

Comment: This question is more for DBAs or sysadmins, rather than sw developers. You should ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com. But you need to do some logging because it is unlikely that based on a two-sentence description anybody would be able to what has gone wrong.

Comment: I am just to add to exact errors that I received.

**"Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (4936 > 1024). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet's"**

I did make sure that I have set all the parameters in my.cnf and max_allowed_packet parameter is set to its maximum. 

Only reason for me to raise this question here was to know if there are any settings or configuration that we have to increase max_allowed_packet in liferay for example if we can add this in connection string.

Comment: Yeah, but settings are more for DBAs and not so much for programmers. The error message is raised by mysql, not by liferay. Although, I do wonder what could be in a an over 4GB packet.

Comment: Also, make sure you actually set the value to 1024M and not only 1024. I've seen the error message with a lot higher numbers, If the error msg shows the actual number of bytes instead of megabytes this is your solution...